# How do get value from async function without then()

Tags: react-native

I know I have to use then() or in a async function to use await to get the value from other async function .
but how to I get value directly ?
I try to pass the value in normal function but not work .
there is no other way to get the value  directly  ?

thanks

here is ample :

```
load_data_normal(key){
    this.load_data(key).then((ret_val)=>{
      console.log(ret_val);
      return ret_val;
    })
  }

  load_data = async (key) => {
    const MMM = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    return MMM;
  }
```

load_data function just work with then(), but load_data_normal not work ,
I just want to get value from get_data without then ..

Comment: Could you please give us more information, like a piece of the code or the context?

Comment: edited , check it out

Comment: load_data_normal @guilhermevictorramalhonatal not work

Answer (score 0):

Normal function doesn't work with await. You need an async function.

```
const asynFunction = async() => {
 
         const results = await fetch(url);
         console.log('results', results)
}
```

If you don't want to use async, you need to create a new promise.

```
 const load_data_normal = (key) => {
    localStorage.setItem("abc", "somevalue in abc");
    load_data(key).then((resuls) => {
      console.log("abc", resuls);
    });
  };

  const load_data = (someKey) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(localStorage.getItem(someKey)));
  };
  load_data_normal("abc");
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-liskov-1n0nq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I know that but what about my normal function , I edit my question .

Comment: I saw this thank you , but is any way to get return value from load_data_normal and use it on other value ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is just adding async to your load_data_normal, if you want to know more read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```
load_data_normal = async (key) => {
    const ret_val =  await this.load_data(key);
    return ret_val;
  }

  load_data = async (key) => {
    const MMM = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    return MMM;
  }
```

Comment: Ok , but what about the usage of that function  it shoud be await for async too , its no way to get the values without async  ?  I just  write load_data_normal to prevent it from async

Comment: well, it's an async operation, you must wait until is done, or you use async or pass data to your .then(). There is no way to create async operations and don't use some kind of async operator, the await and async are designed to make the code cleaner (they make you write your code in a sequential order).